# Concatenating string from SSIS for loop task

Tags: for-loop, ssis, concatenation

I have an SSIS package which loops over an array of dates. On each iteration I would like to append the current date to a string to get a full string of all the dates iterated.

What I did was to make an expression where: dateconcatvariable + ", " +currentdatevariable

However, dateconcatvariable  is resetting on every iteration of the for loop and so in the end I end up with the last date iterated over instead of all the dates.

the variable is a package level variable.

Any ideas on how to get a concatenation to happen on SSIS?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit lost on your design. Could you post a screen shot of the Control Flow and the Data Flow?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out using a script task.

Answer (score 1):

```
1. Create a string variable @User::var
2. Use an Expression component and set the expression to @User::var = @User::var + (WSTR, 15)@User::yourdatevar
```

This should give you the general idea.